# Counting Comments as Singular and Plural in comments.php Template

Tags: comments

I need help on how to count single and plural comments in relation to how the text is formatted.

**Current output:**
Discussion: 1 comments and 1 answers

**Desired output:**
Discussion: 1 comment and 1 answer
or, when plural - as above.

I've been trying this back and forth and I am stuck.

**This is my code from my comments.php template:**

```
<?php
$number_of_parents = comment_counter($post->ID);
$number_of_children = $post->comment_count - $number_of_parents;
?>
<?php if (have_comments()) : ?>
<h3 class="comments-title">Discussion: 
<?php if ($number_of_children > 0){
echo ''.$number_of_parents.' questions and '.$number_of_children.' answers.';
} else {
echo 'Questions: '.$number_of_parents.'';
} ?></h3>
```

**The function relates to this function, which I have in my functions.php file:**

```
function comment_counter($id){
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT COUNT(comment_post_id) AS count FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE `comment_approved` = 1 AND `comment_post_ID` = $id AND `comment_parent` = 0";
$parents = $wpdb->get_row($query);
return $parents->count;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that I understand. But I don't know how. I don't write code as such. Could you perhaps provide an example?

Comment: This is what the `_n()` function is for: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_n/

Comment: Thanks. That does help a lot! Have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick...

```php
<?php
    $number_of_parents = comment_counter($post->ID);
    $number_of_children = $post->comment_count - $number_of_parents;
?>
<?php if ( have_comments() ): ?>
    <h3 class="comments-title">Discussion: 
        <?php if ( $number_of_children > 0 ): ?>
            <?php echo implode( ' ', [
                printf( _n( '%d question', '%d questions', $number_of_parents ), $number_of_parents ),
                __( 'and' ),
                printf( _n( '%d answer', '%d answers', $number_of_children ), $number_of_parents )
            ] ); ?>
        <?php else:  ?>
            Questions: <?php echo $number_of_parents; ?>
        <?php endif ?>
    </h3>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: While I do not get any errors, the count is completely off and it looks weird. This is the output I get: `Discussion: 2 questions 1 answer11 and 9 ` even though I changed the second argument into `_children` instead of parents. Any other ideas?

Comment: I fixed it myself. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.